# Find a subgraph whose edge weights sum to at least the number of nodes

Tags: algorithms, graphs, decision-problem, polynomial-time

> Given a graph G = (V,E)
>   every edge is assigned a real number Xe $\in$ [0,1]
>
> The sum of x variables for all edges is equal to the number of edges -1 : $\sum x_V = |V|-1$
>
> For a subset S $\subset$ V let us denote by $E_{(S)}$ the set of all edges with both endpoints in the subset S.
>
> Give a polynomial time algorithm that takes as an input graph G and numbers $X_e$ for e $\in$ E, and either finds a subset S such that
>
> $\sum_{e \in E(s)} X_e  > |S|-1 $
>
> or says that no such set S exists.

Analysis of its correctness and its running time.

Any suggestion please ?

---------------------------- IDEAS

1. #### [min-cut project selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem#Project_selection_problem)
2. #### [min-cut baseball elimination](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse421/12wi/slides/07flow.pdf)
3. #### dynamic programming

   I was trying to build a list of dictionaries, storing for each node, the sum of the edges of every subgraph in which it is.

work in progress..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very similar to the classical *densest subgraph* problem, in which you want to maximize the ratio $|E(S)|/|S|$. Goldberg gave a [polynomial time algorithm](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1984/CSD-84-171.pdf) for this problem based on network flow. Perhaps you can use his ideas to solve your specific problem as well.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be helpful for the way I'm reasoning (see Edit), may be it can be helpful to give a starting point to a dynamic programming approach

Comment: Nobody said your way of reasoning can succeed (though for all I know, it might).

Comment: that sounds pretty obvious man.
Despite that project-selection and baseball elimination seems to resolve it